# common Value for each row in a single column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I'm trying to find a duplicate value for each row in a specific column in the pandas dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,['A','B','C']],[1,['C','D','F']],[1,['C','E','F']],[2,['E','G','F']],[2,['E','D','H']] ],columns=['id','tag'])

df
Out[1]: 
     id      tag
0     1   [A, B, C]
1     1   [C, D, F]
2     1   [C, E, F]
3     2   [E, G, F]
4     2   [E, D, H]
```

I have a list named "Tags" that contains couple tags

```
Tags = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
```

For each tag in the list, if the number of tag's frequency is equal to the number of id's frequency, then the tag will be given to that id. For example, for id 1, tag C shows up 3 three times and there are also 3 id 1 so that id 1 is matching with tag C.

Is there anyway to make the output that looks like the following?

```
Out[2]: 
     id      tag
0     1       C
1     2       E
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the common value among all lists per group use [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate) with a bit of `set` logic:

```
new_df = (
    df.groupby('id')['tag']
        .agg(lambda l: set.intersection(*map(set, l)))
        .reset_index()
)
```

`new_df`:

```
   id  tag
0   1  {C}
1   2  {E}
```

Optional [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas-series-explode) to unwrap the sets:

```
new_df = (
    df.groupby('id')['tag']
        .agg(lambda l: set.intersection(*map(set, l)))
        .explode()
        .reset_index()
)
```

`new_df`:

```
   id tag
0   1   C
1   2   E
```

---

To get any value in `Tag` list which has the same number of values as the size of the groups use:

```
df['size'] = df.groupby('id').transform('count')
df = df.explode('tag')
df = (
    df[df['tag'].isin(Tags)]
        .value_counts()
        .reset_index(name='count')
)
df = (
    df[df['size'].eq(df['count'])]
        .drop(['size', 'count'], axis=1)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

```
   id tag
0   1   C
1   2   E
```

---

Without Filtering with `Tags` list:

```
df['size'] = df.groupby('id').transform('count')
df = (
    df.explode('tag')
        .value_counts()
        .reset_index(name='count')
)
df = (
    df[df['size'].eq(df['count'])]
        .drop(['size', 'count'], axis=1)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Comment: Just one more follow-up question: if the data has 3X for id 1, but X is not in the 'Tags' list, how should it still keep C as a tag for id 1? Thanks

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean. What do you mean “has 3X for id 1 but X is not in the ‘Tags’ list?

Comment: I mean                                                                                               
 ```df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,['X','B','C']],[1,['C','X','F']],[1,['C','X','F']],[2,['E','G','F']],[2,['E','D','H']] ],columns=['id','tag'])```
so now the data frame has X for each id 1, but in the "Tags" list X is not in it.   ```Tags = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']``` How should I still keep C as a tag for id 1 since C is in the list? Thanks

Comment: See the second to the last code block. (The first one after the first horizontal bar.) "To get any value in Tag list which has the same number of values as the size of the groups use"